# React component partially loaded into Jekyll page

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, jekyll, postcss

I'm trying to embed a React component into a Jekyll page. I've managed to make it appear into the page, but Tailwind styles and some external components/libraries in it won't work. For example, there's a Loader component that shows a loading icon whenever the users makes an API call, but that's never shown. Although all those things will work fine if the component gets rendered inside the React project on a test html site.

I've set up webpack, babel and postcss in the react project, this way I generate a bundle.js file which I add into the html page of the Jekyll project, but as said, some things get lost in the way.

On the Jekyll side, I've simply added bundle.js file in the assets folder, added a script tag, added a `<div id="react-app" style="width: 250px;"></div>` and that's it.

My config files look like this:

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js', 
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'  
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/,  
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',  
        },
      },
      // This will not work
      // {
      //   test: /\.css$/i,
      //   use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      // },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.css',
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.jsx'],  
  },
};
```

**tailwind.config.js:**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    require("tailwindcss/plugin")(({ addVariant }) => {
      addVariant("search-cancel", "&::-webkit-search-cancel-button");
    }),
  ],
};
```

**postcss.config.js**:

```
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'postcss-preset-env',
    tailwindcss
  ],
};
```

index.js:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "external-library/lib/style/fonts.css";
import SearchBox from "./components/SearchBox";
// import 'tailwindcss/tailwind.css'; // not necessary since index.css has @tailwind annotations
import './index.css';

export { default as SearchBox } from './components/SearchBox';

// ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <SearchBox />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('react-app')
);
```

So far I've tried importing the index.css file into index.js, I've used different css rules on the webpack.config.js file, I've configured PostCSS, I extracted the css file and added it into the html on the Jekyll site using MiniCssExtractPlugin (the file goes into the assets directory)...